# Python tabulate format: want to display the table with one blank element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to use Python's tabulate format. I want to get my data in the following way:

```
x    1
y    2   3
z    4   5
```

My code is like this:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = [["x", 1], ["y", 2, 3], ["z", 4, 5]]
print tabulate(table)
```

But, with this, I am getting an output:

```
-  -
x  1
y  2
z  4
-  -
```

That means it suppresses the second data for every attribute. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You could do it like `table = [["x",1, None],["y",2,3],["z",4,5]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most basic form you could do

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = [["x",1, None],["y",2,3],["z",4,5]]
print tabulate(table, tablefmt='plain')
```

`tablefmt='plain'` suppresses the dash formatting, as per your example output.

Output

```
x  1
y  2  3
z  4  5
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to add "None" to the table, in a way that tabulate will not ignore the column.

To do it, you can use:

```
table = [i + [None]*(max(map(len, table))-len(i)) for i in table]
```

Than just use:

```
print(tabulate(table, tablefmt='plain'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
for digit,letter in zip([1,2,3],['x','y','z']):
    print digit,letter,
```

Comment: you can add some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

In arrays, **the number of columns must be equal to the number of columns in the rest rows.** In the example, you made one of the lists whose number of columns is different from the number of columns in the rest of the lists, so use `"None"` as the third value.

solution:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table = [["x", 1, None],
         ["y", 2, 3],
         ["z", 4, 5]]
print(tabulate(table))
```